# ImportError: No module named request. The error isn't coming from my code

Tags: python, import, package

I'm trying to import a package called populartimes: https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes

I keep getting this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
    import populartimes
  File "../site-packages/populartimes/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .crawler import run
  File "../site-packages/populartimes/crawler.py", line 12, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

When I run:

```
pip install requests
```

I get:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /.../2.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /.../Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /.../Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /Users/aelsabagh/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /.../Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2020.4.5.1)
```

and when I run:

```
pip install urllib3
```

I get:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /.../Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.25.9)
```

Comment: `pip install requests` - make sure you have the requests library installed. Also, I belive the library is for Python 3, make sure you are using Python 3

Comment: Hi, please try to put output into block code tags. That will make it easier to read. Examples here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: @GTBebbo I've done that already and still get the same problem!

Comment: Try `pip install urllib3`

Comment: I updated the post with the result I get when I try to install urllib3 and requests :)

Comment: There is actually No module named "request". Instead, it is "requests". It is a simple typo.